# Convert xls to xlsx with excess headers

Tags: python, excel, file-conversion

junior dev here.

**Goal:** Using python, convert file type from xls to xlsx that contains a clean header.

**Desired header:** [image]

**My attempt:**

My first attempt was to use [win32com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918646/how-to-convert-xls-to-xlsx). However, that didn't work because I received the following two errors when pip installing. I believe it's because I'm on a  Mac.

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement win32com (from versions: none)`

`ERROR: No matching distribution found for win32com`

I then followed this [post that doesn't use win32com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68897299/convert-xls-to-xlsx-without-win32com), however, that produced this error.

`xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'<?xml ve'`

The other issue I'm running into is my file itself. At the top, there are 6 extra lines that need to be removed. In addition, my headers of the actual data table have a mix of merged and unmerged cells. I'm not certain how to go about fixing that.

Any suggestions would be helpful and thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the second part of my question. Still not certain on how to take in xls files.

If I convert the file to a CSV file, then use this command to remove the top few lines. skiprows is the method to use that cuts out the top section of a csv or xlsx file during the df's intialization.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv', skiprows = 8)
```